# FluidTYPO3 duplicated Content Modules with Flux Grid at TYPO3 Backend

Tags: grid, typo3, flux, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I'm using `TYPO3 7.6`with the latest `Flux`-, `VHS`- and `Fluidcontent`Extensions ([FluidTYPO3](https://fluidtypo3.org/)). I've wrote a new FLUX-Content Element, a Tab-Container from [Zurb Foundation 6](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/tabs.html).
The element is working fine (frontend), but at backend I have a row with my tabs and also columns .. sth. will dublicated my tabs and the content inside?! Already cleared Cache.

Here's a screenshot. The Tab-Elements will be dublicated, I don't know why?

[image: dublicated content elements typo3 backend]

My FLUX FCE:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
    xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
    xmlns:flux="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Flux/ViewHelpers"
    xmlns:v="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Vhs/ViewHelpers">

    <f:layout name="Content" />

    <f:section name="Configuration">
        <flux:form id="tabs" options="{group: 'LLL:typo3conf/ext/myelements/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:grid.elements'}">

            <flux:form.sheet name="tabs">
                <flux:form.section name="tabs">
                    <flux:form.object name="tab">

                        <flux:field.input name="title" />
                        <flux:field.input name="class" />
                        <flux:field.checkbox name="active" />

                    </flux:form.object>
                </flux:form.section>
            </flux:form.sheet>

            <flux:grid>
                <flux:grid.row>
                    <f:if condition="{tabs}">
                        <f:for each="{tabs}" as="tab" iteration="iteration">
                                <flux:form.content name="content.{iteration.index}" label="Tab {iteration.cycle}" />
                        </f:for>
                    </f:if>
                </flux:grid.row>
            </flux:grid>

        </flux:form>
    </f:section>



    <f:section name="Preview">
        <flux:widget.grid />
    </f:section>



    <f:section name="Main">

        <f:render section="Tabs" arguments="{_all}" />

        <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="tabs-{record.uid}">
            <f:if condition="{tabs}">
                <f:for each="{tabs}" as="tab" iteration="iteration">
                    <div class="tabs-panel {f:if(condition: '{tab.tab.active} == 1', then: 'is-active')}" id="panel-{record.uid}-{iteration.index}">
                        <flux:content.render area="content.{iteration.index}" />
                    </div>
                </f:for>
            </f:if>
        </div>

    </f:section>



    <f:section name="Tabs">

        <f:if condition="{tabs}">

            <ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="tabs-{record.uid}">
                <f:for each="{tabs}" as="tab" iteration="iteration">
                    <li class="tabs-title {f:if(condition: '{tab.tab.active} == 1', then: 'is-active')}">
                        <a href="#panel-{record.uid}-{iteration.index}" aria-selected="true">{tab.tab.title}</a>
                    </li>
                </f:for>
            </ul>

        </f:if>

    </f:section>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
<flux:widget.grid />
```

According to [Release Notes of flux 7.2](https://fluidtypo3.org/blog/news/coming-changes-in-flux-72.html):

> **Preview Widget replaced**
>
> We have replaced the way Flux generates previews when a Grid is
> involved. Before, Flux would render the Grid from the Fluid template
> file which means the template had to be parsed (or loaded from
> compiled cache) and then rendered, involving a significant amount of
> processing. The content element container areas are now rendered by a
> special View class, significantly increasing performance when working
> with multiple nested elements.
>
> The new behaviour:
>
> - Renders a Grid as content element container in the page module if your
>   template defines one, regardless of whether or not you have a Preview
>   section.
> - **Deprecates flux:widget.grid** which no longer has any function.
> - Removes all support for setting the Fluid template used to render the
>   Grid.
>
> Basically, we sacrifice the rarely used template replacement
> feature for increased performance in very frequently executed code.

So, simply remove complete *Preview* section from a template.

Comment: Thank you viktor, I can change it next week, but you'll be right. I don't read the release notes completely ;)   thank you very much. Have a nice weekend! - stefan

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Viktor.

It's necessary to delete **all** `flux.grid`-stuff from yout template.
The whole preview section and some grid/rows at the configuration section.

That's the correct tab-template for `flux`and `zurb foundation`:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
    xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
    xmlns:flux="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Flux/ViewHelpers"
    xmlns:v="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Vhs/ViewHelpers">

    <f:layout name="Content" />

    <f:section name="Configuration">
        <flux:form id="Tabs" options="{group: 'LLL:typo3conf/ext/customerproject/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:grid.elements'}">

            <flux:form.sheet name="tabs">
                <flux:form.section name="tabs">
                    <flux:form.object name="tab">

                        <flux:field.input name="title" />
                        <flux:field.input name="class" />
                        <flux:field.checkbox name="active" />

                    </flux:form.object>
                </flux:form.section>
            </flux:form.sheet>


            <f:if condition="{tabs}">
                <f:for each="{tabs}" as="tab" iteration="iteration">
                        <flux:form.content name="content.{iteration.index}" label="Tab {iteration.cycle}" />
                </f:for>
            </f:if>


        </flux:form>
    </f:section>






    <f:section name="Main">
        <div class="flux grid01Tabs">

            <f:render section="Tabs" arguments="{_all}" />

            <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="tabs-{record.uid}">
                <f:if condition="{tabs}">
                    <f:for each="{tabs}" as="tab" iteration="iteration">
                        <div class="tabs-panel {f:if(condition: '{tab.tab.active} == 1', then: 'is-active')}" id="panel-{record.uid}-{iteration.index}">
                            <flux:content.render area="content.{iteration.index}" />
                        </div>
                    </f:for>
                </f:if>
            </div>

        </div><!-- / tabWrap -->
    </f:section>



    <f:section name="Tabs">

        <f:if condition="{tabs}">

            <ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="tabs-{record.uid}">
                <f:for each="{tabs}" as="tab" iteration="iteration">
                    <li class="tabs-title {f:if(condition: '{tab.tab.active} == 1', then: 'is-active')}">
                        <a href="#panel-{record.uid}-{iteration.index}" aria-selected="true">{tab.tab.title}</a>
                    </li>
                </f:for>
            </ul>

        </f:if>

    </f:section>

</div>
```

Comment: The code above will work but should come with a tiny warning: using `flux:form.content` is a *shorthand method of writing a `flux:grid` with one `flux:grid.row` and one `flux:grid.column` where the column receives the "name" used for the `flux:form.content`*. So in other words the code above generates multiple grids internally rather than creating multiple columns in a single grid. Effectively it renders the same but other use cases trying to copy this approach may find issues, e.g. only the last content column is preserved.

Comment: @ClausDue ist there any alternative for flux:form.content aka simple flux.grid ?

Comment: No, but you get the same result by using one flux:grid, one flux:grid.row and one flux:grid.column. See also https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/pull/1582 which suits the use case described in the original question perfectly and is included in Flux 9.2+